# How to add properties to the relationship in Spring data neo4j when we use createRelationshipBetween

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

For example I want to make relationship between User A and User B and they have RelationshipEntity named MakeFriend, I am used code below, but I am also want to set in relation entity some property values like role = 10.........

```
userRepository.createRelationshipBetween(startUser, endUser, MakeFriend.class, RelTypes.FRIEND.name());

@RelationshipEntity
public class MakeFriend {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String role;
    @StartNode
    private UserEntity startUser;
    @EndNode
    private UserEntity endUser


@NodeEntity
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String FRIEND = "FRIEND";
    public static final String JOYNED = "JOYNED";
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private Long userId;
    private String email;
```

Comment: there is also a separate `RelationshipGraphRepository` which adds some more helpful methods if you extend from that interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could could add the following to your UserEntity class:

```
@RelatedToVia(type = RelTypes.FRIEND, direction = Direction.BOTH)
private MakeFriend friend;

friend.setRole("yourRole");
```

Another way to do it, when you're using the advanced mapping mode, is using one of the  [NodeBacked.relateTo()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/core/NodeBacked.html) methods. Then add the property to the returned Relationship.

And a third way, it to use the [Neo4jTemplate.createRelationshipBetween()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/3.3.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/Neo4jTemplate.html#createRelationshipBetween-org.neo4j.graphdb.Node-org.neo4j.graphdb.Node-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-) method and provide your properties (e.g. role) as the final argument.